# SSIS Error: insert values list doesn‘t match column list

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

In ssis component OLE DB Command:

```
insert into D_MAPPING_CLIENTS (ID, DIRECTORY_ID, SOURCE_ID, BASE_ID)
  values (

     case when exists ( select 1 from D_MAPPING_CLIENTS )
           then ( select MAX(ID) + 1 from D_MAPPING_CLIENTS )

         else 1
     end

  , ISNULL(?, 
      case when exists ( select 1 from D_MAPPING_CLIENTS )
             then ( select MAX(DIRECTORY_ID) + 1 from D_MAPPING_CLIENTS )

           else 1
       end ) 

   , ( select ID from D_SOURCES_CLIENTS where SOURCE = 'D:\load\1\clients.txt' )

   , ?)
```

When I try to save it, i get an error: 'Insert value list does not match column list', although when i run this script in Management Studio it works fine.

What's the problem?

UPD: Where i replace last '?' to some value it works fine :o

Comment: I've replaced last parameter to first posititon and this will worked. I'm confused :[

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is a result of one of two things. Either you have not set up the **Parameter Mapping** in your Execute SQL Task, or not set the **BypassPrepare** setting in the settings of the same task, which is most likely the case.

I managed to recreate your error, as well as bypass it. The steps I followed are as follows:

1. Recreated your DB with just those two tables specified in your query. Tested it out with hard-coded values to be certain that it works.
2. Added two variables to my package - **BaseID** & **DirectoryID** and gave them some default values.
3. Created an SQL Execute Task and added your query to the **SQLStatement**.
4. Went to **Parameter Mapping** and mapped the two variables specifying Parameter names of **0**  & **1**.
   At this point my **BypassPrepare** option was set to **False**, running the task resulted in the exact error you are receiving.
5. Set the **BypassPrepare** option to **True**. Executing the task resulted in success and a row being added to the DB without any problem.

For information about this specific property (used in a different context, but has the same general functionality) see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.executesqltask.executesqltask.bypassprepare.aspx

---

**UPDATE**

The solution given is for an SQL Execute Task, not for an OLE DB Command. Changing the location of the '?' value parameters in the SQL query to the front as stated by the OP works around this issue.

Another option is to fall back onto calling a Stored Procedure.

Comment: But my statement is not a SQL Execute Task, it is **OLE DB Command** in Data Flow Task

Comment: Oh, in that case, what is the source of your Data Flow Task? Have you specified the correct Column Mappings in the OLE DB Command properties?

Comment: Column mapping is correct. I move all parameters in the begin, and now it works fine. I have no idea why it did not worked

Comment: You can use a stored procedure if the ordering is giving you trouble. This seems like a corner case error, which is not documented anywhere (at least I cannot find an explanation)